# How to return to the pre page after user login in struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2

This is my idea, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

At first, I created an Interceptor to validate whether the current user is logged in or not:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        // check http sessoin ...
        if(notLogin) {
            return Action.LOGIN;
        }
        return ai.invoke();
    }
}
```

Then, I wrote the configuration file like this:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="login" type="redirect">   
        <param name="location">/login</param>
        <param name="referrer">${#request['struts.request_uri']}</param>
    </result>
</global-results>
```

But on the login page, the "referrer" parameter is always empty so that I cannot use that parameter to redirect to the page which the user visited before login.

How can I get this "referrer" Correctly ?

Comment: @umeshawasthi `struts.request.uri` is set by struts 2 automatically on other page. I find it by checking `<s:debug></s:debug>` tag's content.

Comment: @umeshawasthi `struts.request.uri` is not available in my interceptor, so I have to get the current url with http servlet APIs.Thanks.